# nginx generate predictable session?

Tags: django, nginx

I deploy my django with nginx and uwsgi
And I have a security issue `The remote web server generates predictable session IDs.`

```
Ports
tcp/80
Sending several requests gives us the following session IDs :

SERVERID=locationserverfarm1|Vv4q4|Vv4q4
SERVERID=locationserverfarm2|Vv4q4|Vv4q4
SERVERID=locationserverfarm3|Vv4q4|Vv4q4
SERVERID=locationserverfarm2|Vv4q4|Vv4q4
SERVERID=locationserverfarm1|Vv4q4|Vv4q4
```

How can I set to let it generate random session id ???
Please help me.  Thank you.

This is my nginx setting :

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 3000;

}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

myweb.conf

```
upstream django {

    server 127.0.0.1:8001;  
}

server {

    listen     80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;  
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    #security
    add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";


    location /static {

        alias /usr/share/nginx/ENV/mysite/mysite/staticfiles;  

    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed

    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexeyTen I add it.

Comment: I don't see where nginx generate any cookie. Fix you application.

Comment: I didn't understand. You mean it's django problem ??  Not nginx problem??

Comment: Find out who sends this cookie. Either you didn't show us full nginx config, or nginx has nothing to do with it.

Comment: BTW, I don't think it's a session. Looks more like a server affinity

Comment: Thank you. It's my all nginx setting.  I will try to find it

Comment: BTW Do you think it's related with HAPROXY ?  We have a HAPROXY to distribte the request to 3 nginx server

Comment: It certainly is http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/03/29/load-balancing-affinity-persistence-sticky-sessions-what-you-need-to-know/ see section «Session cookie setup by the Load-Balancer»

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this direction to find the solution